# How to read a file deployed within an EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, war, ear

How can I read a file deployed as a resource within a EAR or a WAR?

I want to create a new FileInputStream calling the constructor below.

```
java.io.FileInputStream.FileInputStream(String)
```

But the file I want to read is located on path "/glm/src/main/resources/excel_templates" inside the WAR file.

Is it possible to create a FileInputStream with a EAR or WAR based filepath?

Comment: It's worth noting that File I/O operations (and multithreading) are discouraged within a JEE container, as they can break transactional integrity. There are a number of alternatives, like JCA connectors, for example.

Comment: I'll keep JCA connectors in mind when writing to a file, but is a RCA connector needed when I just need to read a template file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
URL url = SomeClassInEar.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("rootDirInEar/SubDir/fileInEar.whatever");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Thank's a lot!
If you're using spring you can use the following code too.
    `new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource(FILAPATH_INSIDE_EAR_CLASS_PATH).getInputStream()`